# How to remove an entire list after from master list in java using Iterator

Tags: java, loops, collections, iterator

I have one `List<List<Address>>` object and another `List<AddressList>` Object. I have to iterate through this list and keep deleting objects from list after my 
first loop executes. How can I do this?

```
List<List<Address>> addressLists;
List<Address> addressList;
for (List<Address> listOfAddress : this.addressLists) {
    for (Address address : listOfAddress) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

How can I delete or remove object from `addressLists` after processing?

P.S. I am using Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

Use an explicit iterator:

```
Iterator<List<Address>> iter = this.addressLists.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    List<Address> listOfAddress = iter.next();
    for (Address address : listOfAddress) {
        //some code
    }
    iter.remove();
}
```